# SQL query for Min() and grouping

Tags: mysql

My Table name is powerpro including data as following

```
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| record_no |     date_time     | phase1_energy |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
|           |                   |               |
|         1 | 12/01/14 12:00 AM |           234 |
|         2 | 12/01/14 01:00 AM |           230 |
|         3 | 12/01/14 02:00 AM |           220 |
|         4 | 12/01/14 03:00 AM |           222 |
|         5 | 13/02/14 12:00 AM |           233 |
|         6 | 13/02/14 01:00 AM |           234 |
|         7 | 13/02/14 02:00 AM |           220 |
|         8 | 13/02/14 03:00 AM |           220 |
|         9 | 14/03/14 12:00 AM |           234 |
|        10 | 14/03/14 01:00 AM |           231 |
|        11 | 14/03/14 02:00 AM |           219 |
|        12 | 14/03/14 03:00 AM |           216 |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

I want to get phase1_energy balance (from each day minimum reading deducting by next day minimum reading) back to 7 days from NOW()

I tried this:

```
SELECT a1.* FROM powerpro a1
INNER JOIN
(
  select MIN(date_time) as min FROM powerpro
  GROUP BY date(date_time)
) a2

ON a1.date_time = a2.min 
WHERE date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() ORDER BY date_time
```

But only got the minimum reading of each day as follows.

```
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
| record_no |     date_time     | phase1_energy |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
|           |                   |               |
|         1 | 12/01/14 12:00 AM |           234 |
|         5 | 12/02/14 12:00 AM |           233 |
|         9 | 12/03/14 12:00 AM |           234 |
+-----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Can anyone help me ? Thanks

Comment: could you show sample output as well?

Comment: January 14th 2012? Are you sure?

Comment: No. That is 12th 2014

Comment: Consider providing proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) for the above, and the desired result set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, for each date you want the min time (which you managed to get), and the next day's min time.

Here is how you can get that next day min time (**EDIT:** adding the energy of both days):

```
SELECT DATE(a1.date_time) AS `date`, a1.date_time AS this_day_min_read,  a1.phase1_energy AS this_day_energy,
a4.date_time AS next_day_min_read, a4.phase1_energy AS next_day_energy
FROM powerpro a1
JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_time) `date`, MIN(date_time) AS `min` 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
       ) a2 ON a1.date_time = a2.min 
JOIN (SELECT DATE(date_time) `date`, MIN(date_time) AS `min` 
        FROM powerpro
        GROUP BY DATE(date_time)
       ) a3 ON DATE(a1.date_time) = a3.date - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
JOIN powerpro a4
    ON a4.date_time = a3.min
WHERE date_time BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AND NOW() 
ORDER BY date_time
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes. partially help. But I want to get the difference of Phase1_energy of that two days

Comment: @Manoj - see now. Good luck

Comment: Yes. But I need only the amount of next_day_energy - this_day_energy (mentioned as your code) grouping according to the date_time